# KTable unable fetch data from Materialized view

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams with Spring Boot. In my use case when I receive customer event I need to store it in `customer-store` materialized view and when I receive order event, I need to join customer and order then store the result in `customer-order` materialized view.

```
StoreBuilder customerStateStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("customer-store"),Serdes.String(), customerSerde)
                .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());
streamsBuilder.stream("customer", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), customerSerde)).to("customer-to-ktable-topic",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), customerSerde));
KTable<String, Customer> customerKTable = streamsBuilder.table("customer-to-ktable-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), customerSerde),Materialized.as(customerStateStore.name()));
```

Here is the problem, when I receive Order event and my `customerKTable` returns null and join operation becomes useless. This is not how it supposed to work. My code is similar to [Kafka Music](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.3.0-post/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java) example, I created `TestConsumer` class to test this. Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing/blob/master/src/test/java/com/kafkastream/TestConsumer.java) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was created by `KTable`. The KTable syntax I was using was syntactically correct but not working. Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024465/newly-build-ktable-returns-nothing) for more 
information. Changing KTable syntax worked for me. Now, `customerKTable` returns events or objects from materialized view when Order event arrived.

Comment: Its bit old post but I am facing exact issue with the configuration that you mentioned.i have stream join with materialized ktable but sometime it misses the join and throw NPE, I don't have any idea why it is happening in scala but not in java.